# Can't delete labels from ggdist plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, ggdist

The current plot I have looks as follows.

The code for it is this:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = factor(Class), y = dry_r45, group = 1)) + 
  stat_slabinterval(aes(y = dry_r45), interval_color = NA, fill = NA, slab_linewidth = 0.7, slab_color = "#DDCC77", point_color = "#DDCC77") +
  stat_slabinterval(aes(y = mddl_45), interval_color = NA, fill = NA, slab_linewidth = 0.7, slab_color = "#44AA99", point_color = "#44AA99") +
  stat_slabinterval(aes(y = wt_rc45), interval_color = NA, fill = NA, slab_linewidth = 0.7, slab_color = "#CC6677", point_color = "#CC6677") +
  labs(title = "Density plot for drought exposure, mddl, and wt by Class") +
  theme_minimal() +
  facet_wrap(~ Class, nrow = 2,scales="free") +coord_flip() +ylim(0,1000)
```

This is all great, but I I'd like to get rid of the extra labels that are on the side of the plot, as they are duplicate to the ones on the top.

Some sample data:

```
structure(list(Class = structure(c(1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 3L), levels = c("AMPHIBIA", "AVES", "MAMMALIA", "REPTILIA"
), class = "factor"), dry_r45 = c(363.388145949796, 131.155995859126, 
392.051280340233, 582.12436836741, 633.665139548256, 183.849416151781, 
122.220776927914, 123.221302688033, 664.803469572132, 282.41950446681, 
428.865496826172, 638.74445964881, 573.595947613427, 736.178894042969, 
631.199749226331, 865.028329673332, 184.875174569854, 592.06201171875, 
424.021702785801, 406.961345310191, 957.064789292682, 288.912997795784, 
334.388577027565, 624.237691191004, 566.094641214125, 965.949048973318, 
1086.51134631976, 818.705607823815, 812.030196080853, 418.2314861611, 
930.134145798456, 355.866535987484, 684.294302829476, 556.960110937029, 
398.931482238751, 752.938455770096, 462.381468014355, 398.031650214026, 
298.475676238082, 404.424822059044, 256.658201651774, 596.230151226608, 
729.547485581456, 625.906604886473, 1013.6908622825, 276.346704896106, 
410.053284821958, 541.667721972739, 681.618416008016, 795.054924532415, 
846.914624371795, 1015.57506061187, 611.549468843312, 607.54233085132, 
214.093516755057, 387.734687936783, 847.17546192728, 331.378194899786, 
73.4170806285058, 951.697522815941, 408.532844147008, 412.570369907525, 
281.967407737638, 657.175493623395, 279.812453602327, 244.635951289973, 
872.925850282055, 1261.37923860897, 1235.22716577741, 697.819079558861, 
410.057326599648, 418.804483814327, 837.981430449478, 149.541834271081, 
264.866667957967), mddl_45 = c(230.500439431837, 163.710847456737, 
299.96951929863, 423.873927877018, 440.698367818376, 136.399273290044, 
152.50591804705, 214.297180644848, 722.051286387759, 274.571592029772, 
262.856053161621, 357.064670976097, 295.897055939346, 351.93798828125, 
708.99732498796, 667.473720823298, 117.744196577975, 496.816101074219, 
373.646014965177, 419.876292813853, 747.141463729431, 249.665116104439, 
364.860711117477, 444.033146888809, 535.850235853449, 710.513437306163, 
827.295865526503, 653.396152980815, 757.848262892133, 507.858365499264, 
743.698141956148, 370.792797109154, 288.362213316226, 479.384836448459, 
446.564511233827, 772.255513162575, 517.041371310898, 308.440145695875, 
374.333019052753, 322.049826190655, 304.716008620463, 710.442666526399, 
592.912785708139, 428.822896338398, 710.029178335925, 619.404727700808, 
415.426429585988, 408.516053370282, 413.470117480482, 637.426605185107, 
576.462000244721, 815.561222733534, 716.702217131378, 778.149816356721, 
398.577447637592, 324.873910004304, 628.970334656669, 106.597244141594, 
208.704991215036, 643.954423847175, 417.634095213485, 416.941213162062, 
443.085707354952, 727.496359936908, 344.487907053418, 329.172377352853, 
621.26261704873, 789.666201080418, 824.791253843076, 736.890392529379, 
415.414993990779, 411.323582996079, 639.800383809321, 222.484497747311, 
242.336969253859), wt_rc45 = c(76.3325505422698, 26.0749306037862, 
213.660518472799, 223.602243746736, 260.973150763789, 99.5864348594492, 
69.4877840233901, -0.007544409787213, 165.824787692528, 201.850371611746, 
268.678361129761, 179.384988762923, 300.252028279575, 643.518493652344, 
70.0349630538731, 313.892097528487, 62.9863443202421, 551.368432617188, 
138.110343445225, 127.724954321858, 309.662423873126, 73.4286095145551, 
89.386721275755, 402.7680647483, 178.621465983978, 292.085215506391, 
317.640496352263, 345.16239351255, 495.180555146173, 272.436864661596, 
319.123857185159, 90.7415581058763, 246.418129166891, 201.391396672138, 
113.457046621468, 227.448114313626, 198.105969728023, 220.517736183205, 
99.8547521656706, 235.885256335919, 138.281499654164, 194.346132279175, 
461.937739263605, 244.087637602723, 272.772766122321, -17.0701460841088, 
136.625117421999, 213.479783690862, 265.529688418323, 284.292623990206, 
236.246770851961, 352.069942762743, 186.821549232814, 113.429620774066, 
19.0431269788363, 235.247781032165, 297.818652483379, 67.7614093356662, 
28.8775403752636, 205.488691354048, 134.06130174424, 137.646887953974, 
66.2057470847847, 176.012013026833, 56.2544402972126, 37.3199555074739, 
146.257366275971, 245.445828631319, 239.06573905842, 150.303573937585, 
136.63193962908, 142.41180761378, 331.730189780207, 70.0905639991735, 
93.7739139260316)), row.names = c(NA, 75L), class = "data.frame")
```

EDIT: Answer was given, it was a simple fix using axis.text.y=elementblank()

Comment: Can you please make a reproducible example by either using some standard data, or including some sample data? We can't run your code without going through extra steps of imagining some data for ourselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need `theme(axis.text.y = element_blank()) +` after your `theme_minimal()`, so it alters the theme to have no y axis text.

(Note that I flip the x and y so I can skip `coord_flip()`.)

```
library(ggdist)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(y = factor(gear), x = mpg, group = 1)) +
  stat_slabinterval(aes(x = mpg), interval_color = NA, fill = NA, slab_linewidth = 0.7, 
                    slab_color = "#DDCC77", point_color = "#DDCC77") +
  stat_slabinterval(aes(x = 0.6*mpg + 3), interval_color = NA, fill = NA, slab_linewidth = 0.7, 
                    slab_color = "#44AA99", point_color = "#44AA99") +
  stat_slabinterval(aes(x = mpg - 5), interval_color = NA, fill = NA, slab_linewidth = 0.7, 
                    slab_color = "#CC6677", point_color = "#CC6677") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank()) +
  facet_wrap(~ gear, nrow = 1, scales="free")
```

[image]

Comment: I also added `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(1.5, 1.5)) +` to reduce the extra y padding but it doesn't make sense to me why that should work so I'm not including it in my answer yet.

Comment: Thank you, the labels are gone. Also, how did you move up the lines so they don't collide with the points?

Comment: My data is different than yours. I presume it's because my counts are relatively small; if I use `mtcars |> tidyr::uncount(1000)` for my data the lines come essentially to the points. I suspect there is a way to use `after_scale` in ggplot2 to adjust the lines up or down, but I haven't figured out the right syntax yet.